# Hudson/Jenkins vs Cruise Control vs Luntbuild vs Continuum

Tags: java, continuous-integration, jenkins, cruisecontrol, continuum

I am searching a suitable Continuous Integration tool.

- We have Java and Java EE projects.
- Some of the projects are Maven projects
- We use Subversion/SVN
- Some of the projects have many modules

I searched a little and found these tools as recommended.

Which continuous integration tool would you recommend?

Comment: When you say faster ... do you mean easier to set up quickly, easier to use quickly, quicker to run build/deployment processes (most of this will be down to the compiler and build transports), or something else?  I've not used any of the others, but I've found Cruise Control generally quite pokey ... very usable though.

Answer (score 2):

I have used and setup CC and Hudson so I will speak for only these two. Hudson is easier to setup I would like to think, CruiseControl is about 25% slower. But between both of them I have personal preference for CruiseControl as I found it very easy to extend it to make an online release system for production releases.

Having said that, I see a lot more people use Hudson, and it has enough plugins to support any kind of need you may have.